# Make children of JLayeredPane fill available space of container

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have two JPanel instances in a JLayeredPane, on different z-orders.  I want both of my child JPanels to always fill the space of the LayeredPane.

The idea is for me to toggle the display of a 2nd panel over top of the first to display a modal-like dialog.  Yes, I could just use a JDialog, but I thought it would be fun to try and create some transparancy overtop of the covered JPanel for a nice effect.

I find that using a layout manager on the JLayeredPane, like BorderLayout, and trying to set both children to CENTER conflicts since both panels can't be in the Center.

Is there a trick that I'm not seeing?

Comment: " I want both of my child JPanels to always fill the space of the LayeredPane" You are confused in what you want. If you do this, the top JPanel will obscure everything in the bottom JPanel, since JPanel paints its background.

Comment: Which is the point, as described in the very next paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is for me to toggle the display of a 2nd panel over top of the first

The easiest way to do this is to use a `Glass Pane`.

Check out the [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/) for an example of this approach.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I was looking for.  I might add that I have reviewed a few articles and SO answers by you already which has been very helpful.  Thanks a tonne!

Comment: still have a basic question tho, about how to fill the space of the container.  I tried using a `ComponentListener` on layeredPanel, overriding componentResized to set the size of my child containers, but it sets the size based on mousedown, and not mouseup.  The timing of the size is incorrect.

Comment: Basically, need a super simple layout manager that simply expands the component to the size of the parent!  Wish I could just use CSS on this thing...  gah.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create some "Glass Panel like" overlay for `JPanel`s with `JLayeredPane`:

- Add a `ComponentListener` to the `JLayeredPane` and update the sizes of all child components whenever the size of the `JLayeredPane` changes
- Create a simple `FillLayout`, which expands the size of its child `Component`s to the size of the Layout `Container` (In our case the `JLayeredPane`). You need to keep a list of children `Component`s. During `layoutContainer` you copy the dimensions of the `Container` to these child `Component`s. I wrote this and its really simple, but unfortunately I can't post it, since it's corporate. But if anyone is interested just ask in the comments. The implementation basically consists of one-liners.

For both solutions you need to make sure, that the panels on top are transparent, by setting `setOpaque` to `false`. This ensures that underlying panels render their content.